# Filter doesn't consistently return comment bodies

Tags: bug, api

As detailed in [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/4975/filter-doesnt-consistently-return-comment-bodies), the API doesn't seem to properly return the body for comments. This is a fairly big issue for me, because it means that whenever I want to get a question and its comments, or an answer and its comments (read: "Quite often"), I have to use two API requests, one to get the question/answer and one to get the comments. This 1) gets messy in code, 2) results in more network requests and 3) burns through my API rate limit at double the speed that it should.

Comment: Filters appear to be [terribly broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300151/). Especially comment bodies seem to be a source of [endless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247899/) [frustration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269164/). Perhaps you can figure out a filter that returns all required data by trial and error (i.e. randomly include other fields), but since the filter creation algorithm [is secret](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286718/) that might be rather tedious. As a workaround, you can perhaps save API requests by fetching comments for multiple posts at once?

Comment: Thanks for that; including the HTML `body` field in the filter does get me what I need, as mentioned in one of the posts you linked to. Still a little bit of extra data for mobile users, but at least it's a lot cleaner than having to load comments separately.